# How to retain Apache Camel Exchange's Properties, if message was produced&consumed from RabbitMQ

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq

Currently, There is one instance of Tomcat running, with Apache Camel that produce and consume direct route and it is working fine. For example:

```
    <dataFormats>
        <gzip id="gzip" />
    </dataFormats>  

    <route id="1_consumeAdServerMq" >
        <from uri="rabbitmq://localhost/adserver?queue=ad_google_dfa_reporting&amp;routingKey=ad_google_dfa_reporting&amp;declare=false&amp;autoAck=false&amp;prefetchEnabled=true&amp;prefetchCount=2&amp;concurrentConsumers=1"/>

            <bean ref="dfaReportingFact" method="execute"/>                             
            <to uri="direct:sendToS3" />        
    </route>

    <route id="2_uploadToS3" errorHandlerRef="dlc">
        <from uri="direct:sendToS3" />

        <setHeader headerName="CamelAwsS3Key">
            <method ref="dfaReportingFact" method="getS3Path"/>
        </setHeader>
        <marshal ref="gzip"/>
        <to uri="aws-s3://data?amazonS3Client=#aws-auth"/>
    </route>
```

The first route, "1_consumeAdServerMq" consume a message from the RabbitMQ, and process it via Bean "dfaReportingFact" on method "execute", where "execute" method returns a file object.  lastly, camel route to uri "direct:sendToS3".

On second route, "2_uploadToS3", it picks up the file object, and upload to S3 after gzip.

There problem is, if 1st route completes, and is working on 2nd route, suddenly there is a server restart.  The 2nd route did not complete, and application server gets restarted without knowing to continue.

I tried sending the message to a different Rabbit queue after 1st route (hence even after server restart, it will surely continue), but it looses the Camel Exchange's properties, which i need to complete the entire transaction. Following is the route sample that looses the camel exchange's properties after sending to RabbitMQ:

```
   <dataFormats>
        <gzip id="gzip" />
    </dataFormats>  

    <route id="1_consumeAdServerMq" >
        <from uri="rabbitmq://localhost/adserver?queue=ad_google_dfa_reporting&amp;routingKey=ad_google_dfa_reporting&amp;declare=false&amp;autoAck=false&amp;prefetchEnabled=true&amp;prefetchCount=2&amp;concurrentConsumers=1"/>

            <bean ref="dfaReportingFact" method="execute"/>                             
            <to uri="rabbitmq://localhost/adserver?routingKey=ad_google_dfa_reporting_upload&amp;declare=false&amp;bridgeEndpoint=true"/>       
    </route>

    <route id="2_uploadToS3" errorHandlerRef="dlc">
        <from uri="rabbitmq://localhost/adserver?queue=ad_google_dfa_reporting_upload&amp;routingKey=ad_google_dfa_reporting_upload&amp;declare=false&amp;autoAck=false&amp;prefetchEnabled=true&amp;prefetchCount=2&amp;concurrentConsumers=1"/>

        <setHeader headerName="CamelAwsS3Key">
            <method ref="dfaReportingFact" method="getS3Path"/>
        </setHeader>
        <marshal ref="gzip"/>
        <to uri="aws-s3://data?amazonS3Client=#aws-auth"/>
    </route>
```

In application Debug mode, the bean dfaReportingFact's method "getS3Path" does not have anything there was set during method "execute". My getS3Path code is as below:

```
public String getS3Path(@Properties Map<String, Object> properties, @Header(value = "messageId") String filename){
    // the following code returns **null**, because there is no key match  for "model" in this concurrenthashmap
    DfaReportingModel model = (DfaReportingModel) properties.get("model"); 
    String path = model.getS3Path(adServerInstance);
    logger.info("path: "+ path);;
    return path;
}
```

If the above approach is wrong, what are the safe/best practice to ensure that the route will "continue" or "recover" once the server was restarted (intentional or unintentionally)?

Answer (score 0):

When the Camel context is shut down properly, the [default behavior of Camel](https://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html) is to give enough time for routes to complete. But if the mentioned server shutdown is forced, there inflight exchanges (and the headers of those exchanges) are lost.

We recently had a similar issue where we thought about implementing a custom shutdown strategy that would allow to persist the inflight exchanges and restart the processing when the route comes up again. One pattern we thought about was persisting into files in a custom format, so we would be able to store metadata like Exchange headers and the payloads. In the end, we decided against this and are using the JMS transactions to restart processing from the start of our routes in case of a forced shutdown.

There is an [old thread on the Users mailing list](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Failing-over-in-flight-exchanges-td5725162.html) discussing failover for inflight exchanges with pretty much the same answer.

Comment: I am relying on RabbitMq to ensure a transaction is completed, and that is not my question. I wish to know if i were to use rabbitMQ, how can i ensure that i get to keep the Camel's Exchange header (which include the properties) across all routes?